# Toggle sorting icons in a smart table component in angular7

Tags: sorting, icons, toggle, angular7, ng-class

I've created custom angular smart table component with sorting, pagination, filter functionalities. Problem is sorting is working properly but my table header sort icons are not behaving properly. I found few examples but they all are for angularJS. For example I'm trying to do something like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/gdjc4y39/8/

I've tried using ngclass but it changing all the sorting icons even if I've clicked one.

```
<span  *ngIf="!this.toggleSortIcon"><i class="fas fa-sort"></i></span>
          <span  *ngIf="this.toggleSortIcon"><i [ngClass]="reverse ? 'fas fa-sort-down': 'fas fa-sort-up'"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
 I followed same procedure as in Fiddle link I shared and it worked fine. Add this code in html file `<th *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index;"  (click)="sort(item)">{{ item }}
                <span class="fas" [ngClass]="getIcon(item)"></span>
            </th>` 
and  in ts file you can add the  'sort 'object and two methods exactly as in fiddle.

Thanks.